# How to query GPIO's value?

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I am using raspberry pi B+ board.
I have joined up an infrared sensor to GPIO 12.
I want to use python to query this value, but I am getting "none" instead of a value.

This is the code I am using:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.IN)
value = GPIO.input(12)
print value
```

Comment: How are you running the code?  It works okay for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use GPIO.BCM instead of GPIO.BOARD.
According to your code - it should be like that.

Comment: I don't think so ..this 12 is B plus physical interface. so it should be use GPIO.BOARD.